# What purpose does /embed/ URL have and how to avoid SEO problems?

Tags: urls, seo, embed, iframe, noindex

I've noticed this with many WordPress projects (and clients) over the years so I thought it was worth a public thread. When you interlink a post/page that has embedding enabled, the iframe source will affix `/embed/` URL suffix:

```
<iframe class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" security="restricted" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);" title="Example" src="https://example.com/blog/post/embed#?secret=12345#?secret=12345" data-secret="12345" width="500" height="282" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

However this tends to make [Google GSC](https://search.google.com/search-console/) go a bit crazy because their bots will try to crawl the iframes. WordPress does already include the `noindex` meta tag on those generated sub-pages:

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex, follow, max-image-preview:large' />
```

WordPress also includes a canonical tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/blog/post" />
```

However, for search engines like Google they still assume you want the content crawled because of the `iframe` existing on a public page... resulting in tons of crawl errors in GSC. But because the `rel` flag is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12622886/1718491) on iframes, there doesn't seem to be any easy way to avoid this conflict?

TLDR this seems to be more of a Google problem than a WordPress problem, but I find it strange that the `/embed/` page has the exact same content as the canonical version... so what is the purpose of having both?

Comment: Well look at the embed version, it looks completely different so that it works as an embed. That's the purpose.

Comment: @JacobPeattie That's what I have assumed in the past, but the embed version looks exactly the same on the sites I tested, so I figured if the API renders the iframe styling anyways then why even have multiple URLs?

Comment: It shouldn't look the same. It should look like this: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/01/20/whats-new-in-gutenberg-15-0-18-january/embed/

Comment: Interesting... it looks like that on some sites/pages, but not others I checked. And yet either way, the iframe still looks perfect in both cases, adding to my confusion of why a separate URL is needed if the iframe looks fine either way heh.